# How to create hyperlink in <td> cell of JQuery datatable that does not conflict with alphabet search plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm using jQuery datatables with the [Alphabetical Search](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-alphabetical-search/) plugin.

Alphabet search won't work if I keep any html code between `<td>` and `</td>` .

I wanted to create hyperlink for every cell to a different html page, 
so I did this:

```
<td> 
<a href="demo.html" class="myclass" width="100%">demo </a> 
</td>
```

Alphabet search stopped working.. 
How to fix this please?

Comment: Just made more explicit what this "Alphabet" thing is about.
Also fixed some minor typos.

Comment: Thanks @Haroldo_OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Javascript. The code should be similar to the snippet

```js
function gotoURL(theURL){
  window.location.href = theURL;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td onclick="gotoURL('https://stackoverflow.com/');">demo
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)